# Scrolling of main window content is not working

Tags: android

Hi I am building login screen of my application. I am facing an issue that main window content is not scrolling and it is getting overlapped with the toolbar when keyboard open.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context="com.app.android.login.LoginActivity"
        tools:ignore="missingPrefix">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_view_margin_bottom_8dp">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_registration_layout"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_login_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.InputLayoutStyle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/til_login_password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/login_email"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.InputLayoutStyle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_login_login"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_login_email"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/login_password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:text="@string/login_btn_text"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview_login_forgot_password"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_login_password"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_login_forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/login_forgot_password"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_login_register"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login_login"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_register"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_view_margin_right_8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_view_margin_left_8dp"
                android:text="@string/login_sign_up"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorToolbarTitle"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</merge>
```

[image]

This is how it looks when keyboard is closed.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: @WalterPalladino Can't we have ConstraintLayout inside Scrollview ?

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use it that way, you could try clearing the top margin/padding you've to the first ET.

But if that's the design requirement, try this, 
add a value to the `windowSoftInputMode` to the `<activity>` inside your `Manifest.xml` file

```
<activity
    android:name="..."
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
</activity>
```

This will create the activity in such a fashion that i wll not respond to softinput kwyboard pop-ups.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorToolbarTitle"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context="com.app.android.login.LoginActivity"
        tools:ignore="missingPrefix">
    <!--No toolbar layout here -->
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_view_margin_bottom_8dp">

          ..... rest of the layout file 
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayou>
```

Try this layout. Basically a Coordinator layout is a linear layout on steroids (this is the actual documentation description :) ) 
Check the line `layout_scrollFlags` this helps you scroll your layout and respond to scroll events. Which works best with the new `NestedScrollView` viewgroup. try this once, check if the toolbar now scrolls up or not, we'll then work on the padding. not much swift with constraint layout. need to read and understand a lot of code.

Comment: It's recommended to use it that way, you could try clearing the top margin/padding you've to the first ET. - what do you mean by margin/padding ? I don't have

Comment: sorry, i read the xml file now. Post your `toolbar` xml file and try the change in the manifest file. it will work, dont forget to add an imeOption to your password ET.

Comment: pls check the edit. its just a try so you need to be patient

Comment: did you try the layout i posted?

Comment: Yup. Gif I posted is of your layout

Comment: remove the flags you had set to the manifest file and then test the layout. Since the flags are set it wont scroll

Comment: Yup I removed that too.

Comment: Ummm, try with this flag:  ` android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Answer (score 0):

add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to your parent